# What is this Australian plant with small red berries?

Tags: identification

Can anyone tell me what this is? It was spotted on the coast in Sydney, Australia. The plant with the little berries is what I'm hoping to identify.

[image]

EDIT:

Here's another photo taken September 1st, 2018.

[image: Plant Photo 1-9-18]

Comment: Give me a time lapse over the course of a year and I can tell you for sure!

Comment: I'll try to remember to go back to the spot where I got this photo and get another one, but I'm pretty bad at remembering these kinds of things. I will try though.

Comment: There's another photo @Rob I finally got around to going to the spot I saw it

Comment: If you manage to get another photo, can you try for one without direct sunlight? Without the glare they'll be easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult one - I'm not able to see  any foliage that looks like it belongs to the berries, and the berries themselves are old and dried out because they're probably from much earlier this year. I think where you are it's late autumn, so until new leaves appear, it's difficult to be sure, but these might be the berried spikes from one of the Arums such as Arum maculatum or italicum which would have appeared around three to four months ago. The foliage appears in late spring, and then dies down by midsummer, so that wouldn't  be visible at all right now. The only way to be sure is to wait until more foliage appears when it is spring - A.maculatum has spots on its leaves, A. italicum does not, otherwise, they are similar. Info here https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/1660/Arum-maculatum/Details

Comment: Hmm. Leaves are peltate, not sagitate like Arum. Also the berries: they have a stem (so not Arum), they look empty (so derived from petals or sepals (also not Arum like).

Comment: GiacomoCatenazzi Whilst there are peltate leaves visible, who's to say they're associated with the berry spikes... I'm assuming they're not... arum leaves would not be visible in the southern hemisphere currently. But its just a guess anyway, given the time of year there